# Unity Issue with Asset Pack

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to Unity and when I import [this asset pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/environments/surroundead-survival-game-assets-76276), my project gains 600+ compile errors with most of them looking something like this:

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.visualeffectgraph@4.10.0-preview\Runtime\Utilities\Playables\VisualEffectActivation\VisualEffectActivationClip.cs(4,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Timeline' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

These are the other two errors that are a bit different than the others:

> Script updater for Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aE.dag\Unity.ShaderGraph.Editor.dll failed to produce updates.txt file

> Script updater for Library\Bee\artifacts\1900b0aE.dag\Unity.PackageManagerUI.Editor.dll failed to produce updates.txt file

I have been looking for the fix, but I didn’t find anything.

- I am currently on Unity 2021.1.10f.
- I have Visual Studio 2017 installed, but I’m sure if that helps or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the Timeline package with the package manager?

Comment: Yes I do have installed, Timeline is not the only package that is having the error there are about 600 others that include UIElements,Label,VisualElement etc.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried clearing the Library folder inside of the Unity project folder?

First you should close Unity, and go to the *Unity Root Project Folder*, find the Library folder and delete it.

Done that, reopen Unity and it should re-import everything and hopefully fix the issue!

It can often solve a lot of import errors :)

Answer (score 0):

deleting Library and Packages folders fixed the problem for me